# Fluent UI detailslist basic example how to pass items to the DetailsListBasicExample?

Tags: typescript, office-js, fluentui-react

I am trying to use the Fluent UI Detailslist component from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist/basic)
I just copied the source code and have a (older) class based component which is called DetailsListBasicExample.
the component extends React component, curly braces and an IDetailsListBasicExampleState:

```
    export class DetailsListBasicExample extends React.Component<{},  
  IDetailsListBasicExampleState> {
  private _selection: Selection;
  private _allItems: IDetailsListBasicExampleItem[];
  private _columns: IColumn[];

  constructor(props:{}) {  
    super(props);

    this._selection = new Selection({
      onSelectionChanged: () => this.setState({ selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails()  
  }),
    });

    // Populate with items for demos.
    this._allItems = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      this._allItems.push({
        sortOrder: i,
        propertyName: 'Item ' + i,
        dbID: i,
      });
    }

    this._columns = [
      { key: 'column1', name: 'Name', fieldName: 'name', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, 
    isResizable: true },
      { key: 'column2', name: 'Value', fieldName: 'value', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, 
    isResizable: true },
    ];

    this.state = {
      items: this._allItems,
      selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails(),
    };
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    const { items, selectionDetails } = this.state;

    return (
      <Fabric>
        <div className={exampleChildClass}>{selectionDetails}</div>
        <Text>
          Note: While focusing a row, pressing enter or double clicking will execute   
          onItemInvoked, which in this
          example will show an alert.
        </Text>
        <Announced message={selectionDetails} />
        <TextField
          className={exampleChildClass}
          label="Filter by name:"
          onChange={this._onFilter}
          styles={textFieldStyles}
        />
        <Announced message={`Number of items after filter applied: ${items.length}.`} />
        <MarqueeSelection selection={this._selection}>
          <DetailsList
            items={items}
            columns={this._columns}
            setKey="set"
            layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}
            selection={this._selection}
            selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
            ariaLabelForSelectionColumn="Toggle selection"
            ariaLabelForSelectAllCheckbox="Toggle selection for all items"
            checkButtonAriaLabel="Row checkbox"
            onItemInvoked={this._onItemInvoked}
          />
        </MarqueeSelection>
      </Fabric>
    );
  }
```

What I do not understand is this line:

> export class DetailsListBasicExample extends React.Component<{}, IDetailsListBasicExampleState>

how can I pass an objects Array to the DetailsListBasicExample? Because I would really like to populate the Itemslist but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it?
I tried to call the component like this:

```
<DetailsListBasicExample props={propertyList}/>
```

where propertyList is an Array of objects.
I also tried the following

> DetailsListBasicExample IDetailsListBasicExampleState={propertyList}/>

but I got the famous Typescript error:

> Type '{ props: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<...>'.
> Property 'props' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<...>'.

what I understand is that the property type is wrong. But how can I pass my items list sot it will work?

Has somebody an idea?
I also do not get what the constructur props:{} is doing?

Comment: Nobody from Microsoft providing support for the Fluent UI framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`export class DetailsListBasicExample extends React.Component<{}, IDetailsListBasicExampleState>`

you can write

`export class DetailsListBasicExample extends React.Component<IDetailsListBasicExampleProps, IDetailsListBasicExampleState>`

then you have to specify your `IDetailsListBasicExampleProps` just like the state.

for example

```
  export interface IDetailsListBasicExampleProps {
  myItems: IMyObject[];
}
```

Now you can pass your items like this:

```
<DetailsListBasicExample myItems={  yourItemsHere  }/>
```

Edit: Don't forget to change the constructor as well

Comment: Hi Segoe, Thanks for the advice! It worked indeed. I just had to change the constructor as well. constructor(props:IDetailsListBasicExampleProps).

Comment: Glad to hear :) Yes forgot the constructor

Answer (score 0):

React Typescript (tsx) Sample.

```
import { DetailsList, ISelection, Selection } from '@fluentui/react/lib/DetailsList';

// ...

export const Component = () => {

    const getSelectionDetails = (): string => {
      const selectionCount = selection.getSelection().length;
      return selectionCount
        ? `${selectionCount} items selected: ${selection.getSelection().map( (i: any) => i.key ).join('; ')}`
        : 'No items selected';
    }
    
    const createSelection = () => {
      return new Selection({
        onSelectionChanged: () => setSelectionDetails(getSelectionDetails()),
        getKey: (item: any) => item.key
      });
    };
      
    const [selection, setSelection] = React.useState(createSelection());
    const [selectionDetails, setSelectionDetails] = React.useState('');
    
    return <>
        <DetailsList
            // ...
            selection={selection}
            selectionMode={SelectionMode.multiple}
            // ...
        />
    </>;
}
```